# ld: warning: directory not found for option: -LC_ID_DYLIB=/usr/lib

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I'm using OSX command line gcc and attempting to build a dynamic library. when I do the build I get the following warning.  How is it it is not finding this library given /usr/lib is well known?  And /usr/lib does indeed exist on my machine

this is what I am using:

```
gcc -arch i386 cata/*.c -dynamiclib -o build/cata.dylib -LC_ID_DYLIB=/usr/lib
```

Thanks

Comment: with `gcc`, the `-L` is the start of a parameter that is expected to contain a path to a directory that contains libraries.  What the posted line, seems, to be trying to do is set some environment  variable to `/usr/lib`.  That is not correct.  What is `-LC_ID_DYLIB` and how is it being used in the program?

Comment: the parameter: `-dynamiclib` is also not a valid parameter,  Suggest reading the `http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html` page, which lists all the valid parameters for `gcc`.  You might want to look at the difference between using the `-static` parameter and not using that parameter.

Comment: hi, my apple developer guide seems to state both of the parameters were fine to use.   however i appear to have a workaround for it now.  the problem that made me want to use this is the dynamic library i am building inherits the path 'build/cata.dylib' in its dynamic load string. -- anything that wants to use it has to go find it in 'build/cata.dylib' relative to where they are located.  which is very inconvenient.   i'll answer it myself on how i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

the way i solved it was to make it so the string that got stuck in the library (on where to find the library at runtime) was relative to nowhere -- if that makes sense. so it would be forced to use the LD_LOAD_PATH.

I was using the other flags because someone suggested I use them.

so the gcc i ended up using is this:

```
# my tree is like this
# cata/*.c
# build/*.dylib
#
cd build
gcc -arch i386 ../cata/*.c -dynamiclib -o cata.dylib
```

Doing this compiles/makes a library in the same directory where it thinks it is 'used' (basically having no path).  I am now free to put it somewhere else.  When it is later linked at compile time by a different program and then examined using

```
otool -L
```

it appears with no path in front of the library name.   This is apparently preferable as now when the system goes to try to find it it resorts to looking at the standard libraries and eventually finds it (because I install it to one of the standard locations).

In the original way, otool -L was showing it having a required path of

```
'build/cata.dylib'
```

This made it un-findable and which is why i was trying to use the apple documentation to get around the problem.

This doesn't really solve why LC_ID_DYLIB doesn't work.  I looked into the Loader.h file (line 643) and it has room for an identifier(0xd), a path, and a structure, so I don't really understand why my path wasn't getting picked up.  but its two different topics.  Loader.h is runtime and the other is gcc AFAIK.  I'm still learning apple.